# Starting Ubuntu on Windows 10 PC with Secure Boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Ubuntu 16.04 stopped working on a dual-boot notebook after upgrading Windows 10 to 1607 version with secure boot.

What is the easiest way to restore the dual boot?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that ubuntu overwrites the windows boot manager when installing, so when windows upgraded it cannot boot because the windows loader is missing.

I strongly recommend you to restore the windows 10 boot, finish your upgrade(because for some reason windows requieres reboot) and then restore the grub.

You must do a very large task, so let's see

First:

Go and put your windows 10 CD/DVD and boot it if you have a USB is more faster, boot the CD/USB and click in 'repair', go to advanced options and then select command prompt.

Type this:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
exit
```

Second:

Reboot and then you will be able to boot windows, use rufus or burn another ubuntu live cd boot it and then for restore grub . Start a live session.

And in the terminal type.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

It can vary the name of the disk make sure of that using `lsblk` before using it.

That's all

Answer (score -1):

Renato is absolutely right, however if you're still able to boot Windows fine, then you do not need to first use the first step that Renato described above. Your Windows install overwrote your grub boot loader with the Windows secure boot; you can go straight to his second step.

Moreover, this may be a temporary solution, as future updates are likely to do the same thing, and Windows has been known to reinstall the boot changes (of course you can deny this depending on your update settings), sometimes really killing your boot loader. This also depends on your hardware, and effects can vary. See the linked answers below for more info on that.

My recommendation is to first to disable secure boot if you don't need it, then follow Renato's steps. The option to disable secure boot is pretty easily accessible through your bios at startup (press F1, F2, or F12 at startup before the boot loader starts running). Then you won't have to worry about this in the future either.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2234019
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2294337

Comment: Renato is quite wrong actually an so are you. Both of you don't understand UEFI and both of you mix things about Legacy with UEFI and that can't be good.