# Ubuntu won't let me boot alongside other operating systems

Tags: system-installation, windows, reinstall

I deleted the Ubuntu partition and started the Ubuntu installer up on a USB. The first time, I got the option to install alongside windows. However, I clicked an incorrect option and wanted to go back. I couldn't, so I restarted my computer. Now, I get the warning that UEFI mode could erase my other operating systems, but don't have the option to install Ubuntu alongside my other operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that your computer have UEFI activated as default, so when you tried to install Ubuntu, the GPT table was corrupted, if you want to fix things and being able to install Ubuntu without that error message, recovering the Windows Boot Manager can fix all, and then you'll be able to do the installation aswell.

Please see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815982/starting-ubuntu-on-windows-10-pc-with-secure-boot/815991#815991) for repairing your Windows Boot Manager. Just do the first step.

Maybe you'll need another PC for getting the pendrive ready.

Btw if you want a rapid solution, you can configure Ubuntu with the manual installation, but I'm not sure you'll want that because is hard.